# WPF - Style Setter Property Binding

Tags: wpf, xaml

This works.

```
     <Setter Property="Width" Value="300" />
     <Setter Property="Height" Value="300" />
```

But When I change that, does not work.

```
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="{Binding ImageSize, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="{Binding ImageSize, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

and declare

```
    private Int32 imageSize;
    public Int32 ImageSize
    {
        get { return imageSize; }
        set
        {
            imageSize = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("ImageSize");
        }
    }
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Where are you setting the `DataContext` on the item the style applies to?

Comment: On UserControl, 

DataContext="{Binding ElementName = CodeBehind}"

Comment: And then do you have the UserControl named CodeBehind?  The most likely cause is that it is failing to find the ImageSize property on the `DataContext`.  Check your Output window to see if there are any binding errors, and perhaps post more of your code, so it is easier to troubleshoot.

Comment: Thanks Brian. That's very helpfull. 

There is an error on output window: 

Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'ImageSize' property not found on 'object' ''ListObject'

I understood my fault. Thanks again.

Comment: No problem, glad to help.  I wrapped that comment in an answer below so you can check this question off as answered.  Good luck!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most likely cause is a problem with the binding, and specifically the `DataContext`.  I'd recommend looking in the Output window for binding errors (they will not be raised as standard exceptions, but will be captured in the Output window for debugging purposes).  The binding errors should point you in the right direction as far as what WPF recognizes as the  `DataContext`.